# Accessing $route from Vue.js in SPA

Tags: vue.js

Im trying to accesing meta data from my route in vue.

In `routes.js` I have for example:

```
{ path: '/product/:productSlug', 
    name: 'product.slug', 
    meta: { layout: "no-snackbar" }, 
    hide: true, 
    component: require('~/pages/checkout/product'), },
```

It is `no-snackbar` I need to access.

Then in `App.vue` I'm checking to see if this is set:

```
mounted () {
    console.log(this.$root.$route.meta.layout)
}
```

This `console.log` outputs `undefined`. If I `console.log` `this.$root.$route` I get the following (the same for `this.$route`):

```
fullPath: "/"
hash: ""
matched: []
meta: {empty}
name: null
params: {empty}
path: "/" 
query: {}
```

This is not the right path, name, or ofcause meta data. All is empty. Then when I check in Vue devtools, all settings are correct - also the meta data in `$route`.

This indicates that the values have yet not been set at the point of logging, since they are "visible" later. If I `console.log(this.$root.$route.meta.layout)` in a page (not `App.vue`) in `mounted()`, all values are also present as they should.

The problem is therefore in `App.vue`.

What am I missing in order to be able to access `$route` values in `App.vue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `currentRoute` via `this.$router` from any component.

I'm not sure if using `mounted()` to do this in `App.vue` will work, but `updated()` will.

```js
updated() {
  console.log(this.$router.currentRoute.meta.layout);
}
```

Comment: Hi @seantunwin Thank you for your answer - I still get `undefined` with above method, and if I try `console.log(this.$router.currentRoute.name);` I get null

Comment: I tested the answer in my current project before posting by outputting the`currentRoute` Object on `updated()` in my `App.vue` and worked on each route change.

Comment: Ye, I think is should be able to work aswell - still doesn't though. So I do believe something is wrong with the project - im taking over by the guy who created this mess. Now im trying to clean it up

Comment: Are you getting a log message as expected when the route changes, regardless of the value? If so, perhaps deconstruct the log message starting with outputting `$router` and work up from there?

Comment: Hi again! So, I might have something here: If I do `console.log(this.$router.app)` and in console navigate to the meta data under `_route` object, the Meta data is there. If I do `console.log(this.$router.app.$route)` then now it is all `null` - so maybe becuase of the `$route`. But how could I access the meta without using it?

Comment: I noticed you have a `hide` key in the route. Does this affect anything if you remove it? I'm not familiar with that property.

Comment: I have tried and removed it, but doesnt do anything it seems.

Comment: It seems when I put `.$route` I get the error with null?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201887/discussion-between-seantunwin-and-patrick).

Answer (score 0):

Try visiting the route in your browser first for example `localhost:3000/product/foo` then in your mounted method in App.vue add:

```
mounted () {
    console.log(this.$router.currentRoute.meta.layout)
}
```

**NOTE**: You need to be in the route that has the meta property defined in your *routes.js* or else you will keep getting the `undefined` error.

To avoid getting the undefined error add the meta property to every route in your *routes.js*.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Yes, Ive been in the right route all the time, so not a problem with the url im in...

Comment: Just a random troubleshooting guess, did you try to comment out your component require statement then try to visit the route and see if you get a console message?